# Pandas - Row number since last greater than 0 value

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Let's say I have a Pandas series like so:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], name='series')
```

How would I add a column with a row count since the last >0 number, like so:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'series': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    'row_num': [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]
})
```

Comment: `s.groupby(s.eq(1).cumsum()).cumcount()
`

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
s.groupby(s.cumsum()).cumcount()
```

Output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    1
5    2
6    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: And to get this result in the desired format:  `s.to_frame('series').join(s.groupby(s.cumsum()).cumcount().to_frame('row_num'))`

Comment: @chrisc Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this solution?

Answer (score 1):

#### Numpy

- Find the places where the series/array is greater than 0
- Calculate the differences from one place to the next
- Subtract those values from a sequence

---

```
i = np.flatnonzero(s)
n = len(s)
delta = np.diff(np.append(i, n))
r = np.arange(n)
r - r[i].repeat(delta)

array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this numpy solution.