# Python Polars: Number of rows since last value >0

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Given a polars `DataFrame` column like

```
[0, 29, 28, 4, 0, 0, 13, 0]
```

how to get a new column like

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1]
```

The solution should preferably work with `.over()` for grouped values and optionally an additional rolling window function like `rolling_mean()`.

I know of the respective [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56942937/pandas-row-number-since-last-greater-than-0-value) for pandas but couldn't manage to translate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way with `rle_id` to identify the groups to project `over`, and only doing so on the `0` groups with a `when`/`then`:

```py
df = pl.from_dict({'a': [0, 29, 0, 28, 4, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 46, 47, 0]})

df.with_columns(
    b=pl.when(pl.col('a') == 0)
    .then(1 + pl.col('a').cumcount().over(pl.col('a').ne(0).rle_id()))
    .otherwise(0)
)
```

```
shape: (14, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ 29  ┆ 0   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ 28  ┆ 0   │
│ 4   ┆ 0   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ 0   ┆ 2   │
│ 0   ┆ 3   │
│ 13  ┆ 0   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
│ 0   ┆ 2   │
│ 46  ┆ 0   │
│ 47  ┆ 0   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively a translation of [this pandas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56942986/365102), and *nearly* does what you want (simplified, courtesy of [@jqurious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76988796/python-polars-number-of-rows-since-last-value-0/76989139?noredirect=1#comment135721740_76989139)):

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"num": [0, 29, 28, 4, 0, 0, 13, 0]})

df = df.with_columns(
    cumcount=pl.col("num")
    .cumcount()
    .over(pl.col("num").cumsum()),
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
shape: (8, 2)
┌─────┬──────────┐
│ num ┆ cumcount │
│ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ u32      │
╞═════╪══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0        │
│ 29  ┆ 0        │
│ 28  ┆ 0        │
│ 4   ┆ 0        │
│ 0   ┆ 1        │
│ 0   ┆ 2        │
│ 13  ┆ 0        │
│ 0   ┆ 1        │
└─────┴──────────┘
```

The only "inaccuracy" here is that the first `0` starts with a `cumcount` of 0.

---

To "remedy" this, one way is to temporarily prepend a copy of the first row before applying the procedure above:

```
df = (
    pl.concat([df.head(1), df])
    .with_columns(
        cumcount=pl.col("num")
        .cumcount()
        .over(pl.col("num").cumsum()),
    )
    .tail(-1)
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
shape: (8, 2)
┌─────┬──────────┐
│ num ┆ cumcount │
│ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ u32      │
╞═════╪══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 1        │
│ 29  ┆ 0        │
│ 28  ┆ 0        │
│ 4   ┆ 0        │
│ 0   ┆ 1        │
│ 0   ┆ 2        │
│ 13  ┆ 0        │
│ 0   ┆ 1        │
└─────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: If it helps, you can write it without apply: `df.with_columns(cumcount = pl.col("num").cumcount().over(pl.col("num").cumsum()))`